# Image displaying a few pixels outside element

Tags: html, css

My image is displaying outside the element tag, like this:

[image]

Notice that the image itself is outside the element. Tried with both background image and IMG tag. Same results.

HTML and CSS structure:

```css
.class {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: absolute;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 310px;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    
}

.rounded {
    border-radius: 100%;
 }
.class2 {
    height: 25px;
    z-index: 100;
    position: absolute;
    width: 25px;
    right: 0;
    background-size: 25px 25px !Important;
    background-color: black !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
    <div class="class2 rounded" style="background: url('<image fetched with php code here>')" ></div>
</div>
```

The blue square in the image attached above code, is the inspector highlighting and NOT a part of the code/structure.

eThe actual question: Look at the blue element highlighter. That is the element, that the image has been assigned to. Notice how the image is sticking a few pixels out in the top and left side. Why is it outside the element?

I tried `display: flex;` as mentioned in a now deleted post, that didn't fix it.

Comment: What is the question? What is the desired fix?

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear enough - look at the blue element highlighter. That is the element, that the image has been assigned to. Notice how the image it sticking a few pixels out in the top and left side. Why is it outside the element?

Comment: Please make a demo that actually demonstrates the problem. If I click on the "run code snippet" button, all I see is a gray circle.

Comment: @Juhana I added a working snippet. you can only see the problem if you highlight the black circle in the inspector, and then zoom in on it a little bit. You should see that the black circle, is sticking a little bit out of the element on the bottom side and right side. Only by a few pixels though. Thank you for mentioning to add a working snippet along side my image. :)

Answer (score 0):

just change position:absolute in .class (parent) to `position:relative` - that would do the trick. Like so:

```
.class {
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    position: relative;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    margin-left: 310px;
    border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin-top: 5px;

}
```

added later: 
I see it now. That behaviour is absolutely normal cause they were sqares. 
remove radius from .class2 for testing and zoom and you'll see why it happens.

Just adjust position of class2 adding this, and it would be ok. 
    right: 2px;
    top: 2px;

Comment: Didn't quite work, I created a working snippet with a black circle. Highlight the element tag in the browser inspector, then you'll see that it's sticking out by a few pixels on the bottom and left side. But thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If you set:

```
top: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
bottom: 0;
```

This will make the element adjustable by margin.
Then you can add:

```
margin: auto;
```

and it will display the image centered.

```css
.class {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  margin-left: 310px;
  border: 1px solid #E6E6E6;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
.class2 {
  height: 25px;
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  width: 25px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto;
  /*background-size: 30px 30px;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="class">
  <div class="class2 rounded" style="background: url('http://www.lorempixel.com/100/100/"></div>
</div>
```